# How does one change the default browser used by google app engine launcher?

Tags: google-app-engine

How do you change the default browser used by google app engine launcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses your default system browser. You need to set your browser as default that you want to use.

To make Chrome default Browser: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95417?hl=en

To make FireFox Default Browser: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-make-web-links-open-firefox-default